# Custom module form submissions

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to create a module which accesses form submissions and calculates percentages from values in the submissions

How do I access the form submissions from a custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Use HOOK_form_alter to add an additional submit handler to all the forms you want to process. The defined handler function is than called when the form is submitted with the standard variables ($form, &form_state).

Comment: Is that not used to alter the form before being submitted?

My requirement is to create a summary page where I pull the data out of the database and present it. I need to grab the submissions and perform calcs on the values.

Do I just query the forms table directly? or is there a get_all_submissions() hook?

Comment: *** Cant post code block to explain what I have... ****

Comment: Oh right, I misunderstood. Yes implement a page via HOOK_menu and query the results in the database.